# Can I leave headset spacers above and below the stem

Tags: bike-fit, headset

I am in the process of building a bike with a new frame and fork. The groupset will be from a donor bike. When it comes to fitting the bike and cutting the steerer I would like to do some trial rides to check the fit prior to cutting the steerer.Can I leave the steerer long and install spacers above and below the stem until I get the fit correct? Could I leave a spacer on the top so potential resale would be more likely?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. I do this on most of my bikes so I can do a quick fit for a friend when needed and to broaden the appeal for resale. Just make sure to snug up the compression like normal prior to tightening the stem and you will be good.

Comment: And carbon steer tubes are supposed to have a spacer over the stem.

Comment: @user973810: where do you get that from? There's no problem doing this, as long as you stay within the maximum steerer length, but it isn't mandatory either.